# How to create a private temporary table in Oracle 19?

Tags: oracle19c

I am running `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production` in a Docker container.

I created a user with CREATE SESSION and CREATE TABLE system privileges. User also has QUOTA UNLIMITED.

```sql
CREATE USER airflow IDENTIFIED BY pass;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO airflow;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO airflow;
ALTER USER airflow QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS;
```

With that user I attempted to create a private temporary table with the following query:

```sql
CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ppt_temp1 (
    name varchar2(7),
    age int,
    employed int
    ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION;
```

I am accessing the database on Python 3.9.13 using SQLAlchemy 1.3.24.
I get the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00903: invalid table name`

I also get `ORA-00903` when running the query from DBeaver. I have checked the `private_temp_table_prefix` and it is set to the default value of `ORA$PTT_`. I have read through the Oracle 19c documentation and several stack overflow questions and cannot see what I am missing here.

I suspect that there is some privilege I need to add or modify to make this work.

Comment: Your table name starts with `ora$ppt_`, not the required `ora$ptt_`. [It works if you fix that typo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e1a733aa15d8284bccfbba9efcf16b3a)

Answer (score 1):

As stated this was a typo in the table name.